# Trying to Set up a Time Stamp in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My issue is the same as stated in the title. I have the following code implemented, however, it keeps giving me the incorrect time. I am based in New York and need it to show me the time we have here, however, it keeps showing me 4 hours ahead of time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "EST", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Comment: What's the timezone for your spreadsheet? (File/Settings)

Comment: Hi the Time Zone is Eastern Standard Time

Comment: I'm getting a different value to you, but I think the issue refers (somehow) to recognition of civil time zones. I ran the following time zones when it was 05:42:57 in New York City and 10:42:57 in London. "EST" = 05:42:57; "GMT-5" = 05:42:57; "EDT"=10:42:57; "GMT" = 10:42:57. Perhaps you should use "GMT-5" as your time zone. And adjust for daylight savings however you see fit.